# Cannot find resource dictionary in WPF application Mahapps

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I've followed the documentation and for the first time the application has worked good on my project. Today for learn some things on the mahapps, I've downloaded the demo provided on github and with Nuget fixed some missing resource, no problem also here all working good. When I've reopened my project, I saw that the preview of the UI show the classic VS controls and not the control of mahapps, also in the `App.xml` file This row:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />

                <!-- accent resource -->
                <!-- change "Cobalt" to the accent color you want -->

                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Cobalt.xaml" />

                <!-- theme resource -->
                <!-- change "BaseLight" to the theme you want -->
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

show this message:

> error finding the resource dictionary

What happened? Everything worked perfectly!

Comment: In the designer in visual studio?  What about in runtime?  The WPF designer (visual and xaml) is notorious for invalid errors and generally being awful.  It's surprising you got it working once.

Comment: Yeah, I'm working on Visual Studio 2015. Anyway the solution working if I execute the debug, but the problems is the previes that's not appear anymore.

Comment: Have you tried to close the form that gives you the error, compile and reopen?

Comment: Yeah, I've also tryed to reinstall but same errors.

Comment: The error was given in App.xaml

Comment: I too am having the same issue. After spending several hours trying different things, I have given up. I searched the web for solutions and have found a massive number of devs experience same problem, however, I have not come across a solution that will work yet.

Comment: I found a solution for this, come back to vs 2013

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `application.resources` closing tag.
Here is your full code from above:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />

                <!-- accent resource -->
                <!-- change "Cobalt" to the accent color you want -->

                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Cobalt.xaml" />

                <!-- theme resource -->
                <!-- change "BaseLight" to the theme you want -->
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Nope, I missing to paste it here but I've this in my solution anyway I found the fix:
I've changed Visual Studio 2015 to 2013 because the 2015 have a bug in the designer

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. When open the project with newer version of VS (VS 2015) I tried opening in VS2012 and 2013 it worked fine. I seems to be an issue with the VS 2015 designer.